# DOMPDF - break page when not fit content

Tags: html, text, break, dompdf

I'm generating a pdf file with DOMPDF 0.6.0.3 Beta version. I'm generating file with different pages, to which I add a header manually  by placing it in the HTML.

My problem occurs when I have a page that is text only, and the text breaks over more than one page. How can I detect page break and add headers to only one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add content to a document using fixed positioning (e.g. `#header { position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; }`) dompdf will add the content to every page at the specified position. In order to display the content on only *one* page using `position: absolute;`.

Take note that because of how dompdf renders a document absolutely-positioned content will be rendered on the current active page. So if you want your header on the first page add it to the HTML document prior to you main content.